# Adding pre-install code to the netbeans platform "package as" installers

Tags: netbeans, deployment, platform

I have built an application that installs and runs fine on my Windows computer on the first install.  I wish a computer novice to be able to re-install it from scratch.  At this time, I have to manually delete the directory where the installer puts it.   C:\ProgramFiles.....   This is trivial code that I would know how to write, if I could get to a pre-install area within the deployment installer.  How can I get this code into the deployment installer?

Alternately, is there an option the user could push to delete the previous version.  The deployment 
installer obviously knows that the previous files are already there?   Other installers say something like "Do you want to re-install" and then take care of the problem.

I would also like to include my version of the java virtual machine with my deployment.   I have found several descriptions of how to do this, but they do not always agree.

I am new to java, ant and Netbeans but have over 50 years programming experience.  This is an elegant solution to many standard programming problems.  It seems a shame that two conceptually simple 
holes should  exist.

Ann Maybury